# Collapse Detail Rows on click of master row Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a hierarchical kendo grid which have sub grids upto 'n' level's (binding to remote data). When I click on collapse on the master node all the child nodes inside that master should also get collapsed.
Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthik Ganesan